# Creating points along line at ellipsoidal distance

Tags: qgis, distance, qgis-3, ellipsoid

I need to create points along a polyline in QGIS 3 at every 1000m of ellipsoidal distance and have tried several tools, as suggested in other answers:

- Points along geometry
- QChainage plugin
- Convert lines to points (SAGA)

All of these can create points along a straight, two-node line, but do so at planimetric distances, so when I measure with my measuring tool (in planimetric mode) I get 1000.000 m:

[image: point distances planimetric]

However, if I switch on the WGS84 ellipsoid distance measurement, I get a deviation:[image: point distances ellipsoidal]

I'm working in WGS84/UTM32N. I already know the ellipsoidal length of my line and the last measurement point at the end of the line should have the same ellipsoidal value.

Is there any way to do this in QGIS 3? Am I missing some basic coordinate system logic? I am working in a UTM CRS, which is planimetric, I guess?

Comment: Maybe the [Geodesic Densifier](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeodesicDensifier/) or the [Shape Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/) Plugins could be useful

Comment: UTM projection involves stretch at around the edge of its zone (coefficient varied by `0.9996/cos(theta)` ).  If you are working in the area close to the margin of UTM zone, the distance measured in UTM will be longer than that of ellipsoidal calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I would believe that you need to project the line to a azimuthal equidistant system, centered on the line origin.

```
Proj4: +proj=aeqd +lat_0=LINE_ORIGIN_LAT_HERE +lon_0=LINE_ORIGIN_LON_HERE +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Densify there and then verify measuring the ellipsoid distance. It should work..